# Symfony 2 - Create link to uploaded assets

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I link to uploaded assets dynamicaly with Symfony 2 and twig? I have a Controller that uploads files to the folder `/web/uploads/entityName/fileName`. In the template I'm trying to use the `asset(document.path)` function to create a link to the images. The problem is that the function returns the a path of `/web/fileName`. How can I add the missing path parameters (`uploads/documents`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the url to Twig from the controller.
`// Controller

$twig_params = array('uploadedURL' => $uploadedURL);

$this->render('VendorBundle:someTemplate.html.twig', $twig_params)`

`// Twig

<img src="{{ uploadedURL }}" />`

Comment: Good idea to put the path in the controller - then you don't have to change the URL in the template if you may change it!

Answer (score 7):

Use the Twig string concatenation operator "~", like this:

```
asset('uploads/documents'~document.path)
```